# User ids became numbers and I can't ssh to remote machine anymore

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, authentication, ubuntu-server

I am working with a remote Ubuntu server using `ssh`, and today, while the machine was under a good load of work, I got hit by this weird error.

Checking processes with `top/htop`, I could no longer see user names, which were replaced by numbers.

At the same time, trying to open my screen sessions resulted in the error: `getpwuid() can't identify your account!`.

I could not connect a new ssh session to the machine: as I do that, I get prompted to insert a password, which, even if correct, does not result in access but in `Permission denied, please try again`. The same credentials work on other machines under the same administration system.

I am just a user with no understanding of the system. Could it be that a key process monitoring users/logins got stuck? As I don't have a responsive sysAdmin at the moment, I would like to understand as much as possible this issue, so I can propose some ideas for troubleshooting.

Sorry if this sounds generic, but now I don't have access to the said machine, so it's hard to fetch any more detail beyond what I noticed. Thank you for any hint

Comment: It sounds like it's lost your user account (maybe all accounts?). See if you can read /etc/passwd and whether your account is still there (or is your account in LDAP or something?). I would recommend *against* logging out or rebooting until you know more about what the problem is -- that may just remove the partial access you have now.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, I did log out in the end (bad choice). Other users have the very same problem. The machine won't let anyone connect. At this point, I guess the only route is to restart it; I was hoping to be able to do something about it, but without ssh letting me in I don't see a way out

Comment: Yeah, if you logged out, physical access to the server's pretty much required. Not sore if rebooting will help, though; it depends on what's actually wrong. Good luck!